# Is it possible to use RabbitMQ streams with Celery?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

RabbitMQ introduced [streams](https://blog.rabbitmq.com/posts/2021/07/rabbitmq-streams-overview) last year. They claim streams work with AMQP 0.9 and 1.0 as well as mentioned [here](https://rabbitmq.github.io/rabbitmq-stream-java-client/stable/htmlsingle/#other-way-to-use-streams-in-rabbitmq). That is, theoretically we should be able to create a queue backed by a stream, connect as many workers we need to fan-out to the queue and each worker should get the message delivered.

My question is, has anyone tried to use streams with celery yet? If so, please share any info on how to configure streams in Celery and your experience with them so far. There are unfortunately no blog posts nor any documentation I could find on this topic. I am hoping this post brings together all this information in one place.

The big advantage of streams is they allow large fan-out using the existing infra of RabbitMQ + Celery.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware of there is no way Celery can utilise streams. However, you can probably spin up a long running Celery task that processes particular stream. This is probably reason why nobody attempted (or better say recorded as a blog post or something similar) to do this. - Why bother using Celery for something it is not made for?

Comment: Celery should be able to use streams as RabbitMQ streams support AMQP [https://rabbitmq.github.io/rabbitmq-stream-java-client/stable/htmlsingle/#other-way-to-use-streams-in-rabbitmq]. The reason to use streams is to do large fan-out optimally + have the ability to re-connect a worker and process older data.